# Checking for internet connection on Mac and Windows

Tags: macos, cocoa, mfc, connection, msdn

I want to check the validity of my network connection.

Can anyone please tell me how to do it on both windows (msdn) and Mac.

If there is no api, can I ping an all time live address like google.com and check if it responds or not, if yes how to ping in Windows and Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Mac you can use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) Example.

> The Reachability sample application demonstrates how to use the
>   SystemConfiguration framework to monitor the network state of an
>   iPhone or iPod touch. In particular, it demonstrates how to know when
>   IP can be routed and when traffic will be routed through a Wireless
>   Wide Area Network (WWAN) interface such as EDGE or 3G.

This example will work for cocoa.

Comment: Why was this upvoted when it clearly doesn't answer the question "windows (msdn) and Mac."?

Answer (score 0):

Ping is universal.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ping.mspx?mfr=true

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3040855?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I am writing some code in which i want to do xyz if network is connected and something else if it is not.

Comment: Peter if you're writing code to  do this, whatever language you're writing in should have the ability to connect to a known, reliable source to ensure that the connection is up.

Comment: Yeah, a lot more context is needed to have any idea of what is going on.